# What is the meaning of “more is more”?

Tags: meaning

In a documentary there was a sentence in which it says *"this is the city of more is more*".

I already knew the meaning of *less is more*, but that was new to me.

And when I was trying to find out a good definition in dictionaries, to my surprise, there was nothing (not, at least, in ODO, TFT, Cambridge, MW).

The meaning, however, was quite clear for me from the context.

But I think it's worth asking the meaning of this phrase here.

Comment: I'm guessing the city referred to isn't St Davids.

Comment: Do we have to guess which city the documentary was talking about? It's probably Beverly Hills, Texas, Seoul, or Dubai,  or any city that boasts of excess, and encourages consumerism on a wide scale.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You hit the nail on the head. Actually I didn't want to mention the city's name, but that was Dubai.

Comment: It's probably not in any dictionary because it is more of a cultural statement, a maxim or ethic, than it is a set phrase.

Answer (score 7):

***[More is more](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/33/messages/717.html)*** is just the opposite of the saying "less is more". It may be used to suggest that in some cases, "less" is not the better or more appropriate way to go:

> - There is a saying "**Less is more"*** which means that when something is understated or done in a low-key manner, it's much more effective than if it were done with a lot of fanfare and exaggeration.
> - ***"More is more"*** would be a variation, the flipside, of the above philosophy.

(The Phrase Finder)

- The "city of more is more" suggests the idea of the "city of excesses".

Comment: Mies van der Rohe picked up the phrase "less is more" from Robert Browning's poem, Andrea del Sarto,  and made it a principle of architecture.
To paint a little thing like that you smeared 
Carelessly passing with your robes afloat,— 
Yet do much less, so much less, Someone says, 
(I know his name, no matter)—so much less! 
Well, less is more, Lucrezia:
This dictum reminds me of Mark Twain's advice ",As to the adjective, when in doubt strike it out."

Answer (score 0):

"More is more" is from rem koolhaas, another architect. It is an edit from "less is more" and an answer for the critic "less is bore" Its about the complexity that rulez the cities of the new era and an expretion of the demografic growth that the first one doesnt understood. It is also refered to something that he learned in japan where every single thing was in a list and must be checked to continue (I think it is the fukuoka housing proyect) if you want to know more there is a book S M L XL by Rem Koolhaas. Go to the library because is heavy big and $

PD: "More and more, more is more"... the long one

Answer (score 0):

More is more also reffers to the new trend of combining layers of understandings, cultures, experiences as the core of authenticity. This in reaction to the less is more movement that was more monocultural and specific, the new era recognizes its complexity and the energy that is released when experiences and expressions intermingle and disrupt

Answer (score 0):

With "Less is more", there is an appreciation for space surrounding an object. It helps to be able to focus on the thing that matters. Space is a luxury.  Cut the fluff. Straight to the point. Down to the essence. All killer, no filler.

With "More is more", there is more to explore. It's more cozy, dimensional, multi-interpretable. There is a function in the added things that could have been discarded at a cost. It's very human to add visuals to a vase, for instance. The pure function of the vase is to hold water and flowers. The secondary function could be style. The decoration could be considered 'extra' according to the "More is more"-principle. Bonus on top of functionality.